# Show image dropdown on thumbnail hover, hide it when hovering out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image thumbnail, I want it to show an hidden div which contains the same image, but larger, with some description below. It should show the hidden div whenever the mouse is hovering over the thumbnail, and as long as the mouse is hovering this div. But from some reason it's really glitchy: the image sometimes gets stuck or just won't open.
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").delay(800).show(0);
  }, function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Dropdown Image</h2>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <img src="image.png" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <img src="image.png" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have no problem with opening the Div and it's kinda hard for us to find the problem if we cant reproduce the problem.

Comment: the problem starts when you mess around with it, for example click somewhere within the content div and then click outside, I mean, play around with it and a few mouse clicks around and it will be reproduced. Simply hovering it works alright.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my answer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add .stop() before doing your stuff on the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop().delay(800).show(0);
  }, function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").stop().hide();
  });
});
```

How it works: When you mess around with it, it records how many times you did the trigger and then animates it that many times.. or something like that.. So what `.stop()` does is to make sure that when you mess around with it, it first stops any previous animations and does a new one.. So it sort of erases its memory if you will.

Comment: Haha definitely, you just answered so quickly I couldn't mark it as accepted it (first few minutes you can't)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
var dropdowncontent = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
function a() {
dropdowncontent.style.display = "inline-block";
}
function b() {
dropdowncontent.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    
    .desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <h2>Dropdown Image</h2>

  <div class="dropdown" onmouseover="a()" onmouseout="b()">
    <img src="image.png" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
      <img src="image.png" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">Description</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes! Only with a few milliseconds of delay until it shows up. (The original code used CSS hover so the javascript could be skipped)